# Windows Batch file Dynamic create statements

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

I need to get a list of file names from a directory using a windows batch program.  I would like to take each FILE NAME and combine that with another command line statement.
Note i only need the file name not the contents of the file. 
How would this be done?

If i have a 'Data' directory on the D drive with the below files (note there could be many files)

```
--------------
myFile1.abc
myfile2.abc
------------------
```

How could i dynamically create something like this using a windows batch program?

```
move C:\myFile1.abc C:\newdir
move C:\myFile2.abc C:\newdir
```

note - (i know there is a easier way move files but but i am trying to understand the logic so i can use it in a different command)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
for %%X in (D:\*) do (
    echo move %%X C:\newdir
)
```

Comment: for %%X in (D:\DataFiles) do (
    echo move %%X C:\newF
)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I have been trying something similar all morning. It says %%X wasn't expected. Do you have any idea why? This is what happens when i copy it directly into the command prompt. If i double click on the bat file then it just executes and nothing happens

Comment: Also this is script will be run on windows server 2008r2. not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: On the command line you have to use `%X` instead of `%%X`, see `help for` for an explanation. The Windows version doesn't make a difference. You need to provide wildcards to get a list of files, i.e. `for %%X in (D:\DataFiles\*) ...`, I used the `*` for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try on the command line:

```
for %X in (D:\DataFiles\*) do echo move "%~fX" C:\newdir>>logfile.txt
```

It puts all file names from `D:\DataFiles`  in `logfile.txt` (except hidden files).

Comment: Would you explain the "%~fX"?

Comment: `f` makes a file name with path from %X, please see the docu, type `help for`.